# Pandas dataframe: force text format for long string id to appear as text when opened in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, text

I have long Tweet ids (more than 15 digits) saved as a string column in Pandas dataframe. However, when I save them to an Excel spreadsheet and open them in Excel, the type of the column is 'General' and I have to manually format the cell to be 'Text' (otherwise, if I double-click on a cell, it formats it/truncates it to scientific notation). Is there a way to avoid doing this, and to save the format of the cell when saving the dataframe so that when I open it in Excel, it is 'Text'? Or is this a feature, and not a bug?

Here is a short example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['10765432100123456789','10765432100123456788','10023']})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a bug. That's how Excel interprets large "numbers"

Comment: Excel can be annoyingly ‘helpful’ at times. Perhaps try putting one single quote (‘) in front of the string: easier to use double quotes to bracket the string eg:` “‘10765432100123456789”`